# Windows cmdkey parameters: targetname

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, credentials, command-line-tool

The windows cmdkey command can be used to add credentials for accessing remote resources.

[cmdkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey)

For the most part, it is clearly documented.  One part that is *not* is the *targetname* parameter.  For example, I use it to connect to SQL Server databases like this:

```
cmdkey /add:my.remote.sqlserver:1234 /user:me /pass:secret
```

I discovered that I can add the port number on the end quite by accident.  I need it since my company uses non-standard ports for SQL Server.  Today I discovered that you can also specify:

```
cmdkey /add:*.my.domain
```

to add a default credential for all remotes in a certain domain.  Apparently you can't add a port number to the end (or I can't figure out how).

What I'm now wondering is, is the full specification for *targetname* documented somewhere?

Answer (score -5):

You may refer to the documentations of `cmdkey`at following three sources:

1. [Microsoft Documentation about cmdkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey),
2. [Github.com](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/blob/master/WindowsServerDocs/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey.md), and
3. Windows commandline help`>cmdkey /help`

Comment: Those refs don't answer the question